# Background color when very long options in select2

Tags: css, jquery-select2

With select2, when we have a list with very long options you have this kind of background in the list :

[image]

Here is an example :

```js
$('select').select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select>
<option>11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

I want than the background takes the full width. I tried some stuff in CSS but I'm not good enough in CSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the best way

```js
$('select').select2();
```

```css
.select2-results__option{ 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select>
<option>11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can use **width: max-content;** to show the entire line

Comment: Not really because the size will be different on every lines.

Comment: @Dougui can you tell me why this would be the best answer? since you were concerned of preserving the longer word, `overflow:hidden` is just not allowing to view the longer word.

Comment: @VishnuBaliga The best answer is in comment but yes, the answer should be updated.

Comment: @NewDeveloper Can you update you answer with what you gave in comment?

Comment: @Dougui if you are using `width: max-content` , you will definitely have browser compatibility issues. (ref: https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content)

Answer (score 1):

In the above scenario, The select2 plugin is dynamically calculating the width of the select-dropdown, and have declared the width of the inner children (i.e ul,li) to take 100% width of the parent. (mentioned in their CSS file.)

[image]

The issue here is that, select2 plugin has not handled the case for long-text.

This can be fixed by adding a simple css-property to wrap the long-text to new-line. Example:

```
.select2-results__option{ 
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Link to working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/91fpuy64/2/

> Also, It is not good to have a horizontal scroll inside a dropdown from a UX perspective. Hence, I've suggested for word-wrap.

Comment: The problem here is when there is many long lines. The separation between options it's not very clear. I think I will do that if there's no better solution.